# Make JFXtras Window non moveable and resizeable

Tags: window, javafx-2, resizable, movable, jfxtras

Is there a way to make a JFXtras Window (jfxtras.labs.scene.control.window.Window) non-resizable and non-movable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jfxtras.labs.scene.control.window.Window got an update, added the following methods:

```
setMovable(Boolean v);
setResizableWindow(Boolean v);
```